Is the approach I did to justify this limit equality correct?
I am reading a solution to a problem and got stuck to understand the equality (if $A(t)$ is an invertible matrix whose entries depend in a differentiable way on a parameter $t$ and $ \lim_{h\to0}P(h)=0$):
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\det\left(A(t)+h\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}(t)+hP(h)\right)-\det\left(A(t)\right)}h = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\det\left(A(t)+h\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)-\det\left(A(t)\right)}h $$
I tried to grasp why of this by "foreseeing" the dividend in its expanded form (knowing that determinant is a sum of multiplied entries), analyzing the limit for each term individually and focusing on those that $hP(h)$ appears at least once as a factor , which would look like (each such term) as this:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(hP(h))^nh^kF(t)}{h}, n>0, k \geq0$$
In some sense, it appears that those terms will yield $0$ for whichever values for $n$ and $k$ as if they did not contribute "anything" to the initial big limit, making $hP(h)$ "erasable". However, I am wondering if possible constraints from $F(t)$ (in each individual limit) would be a matter in this conclusion and if I overlook something during the reasoning.
I would appreciate some enlightenment on this approach and any other methods of proving that equality.

By Jacobi’s formula, $\det(A+\Delta A)-\det(A)=\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(A)\Delta A)+o(\|\Delta A\|)$. So, when $\Delta A=h\frac{dA}{dt}+o(h)$,
$$
\det\left(A+h\frac{dA}{dt}+o(h)\right)-\det(A)
=h\operatorname{tr}\left(\operatorname{adj}(A)\frac{dA}{dt}\right)+o(h).
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\det\left(A+h\frac{dA}{dt}+o(h)\right)-\det(A)}{h}
=\operatorname{tr}\left(\operatorname{adj}(A)\frac{dA}{dt}\right).
$$
In particular, this is true when the $o(h)$ term on the LHS is either $0$ or $hP(h)$.
Conceptually, since determinant is a polynomial function in matrix elements, any change in the matrix of higher order than the first order is irrelevant to the derivative of the determinant.
